# How to send JSON with dynamic properties using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I want to create a JSON object that has one dynamic property to send a request to an external API. 
Example:

```
{
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": "val2",
    "prop3": {
        "dynamic_prop": "val"
    }
}
```

This is the only code that gets me a valid response:

```
var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

var body = new
{
    prop1 = "val1",
    prop2 = "val2",
    prop3 = new { dynamic_prop = "val" }
};

request.AddJsonBody(body);
```

However, in this case `dynamic_prop` isn't dynamic. And as I've read anonymous types can't have dynamic props.

I tried using `JObject`:

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse("{\"dynamic_prop\":\"val\"}");
var body = new
{
    prop1 = "val1",
    prop2 = "val2",
    prop3 = jobject
};
```

However the `JObject` isn't serialized properly, I get `[[[]]]`, I'm guessing because that object has numerous other properties (First, ChildrenTokens etc), same goes for `JToken`. I also tried with `ExpandoObject` and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: A json object is basically a dictionary. So try `Dictionary<string, string>` or `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JObject` gets serialized as `[[[]]]` because RestSharp's serializer treats it as `IEnumerable` instead of as a dictionary.

But you don't need to use `JObject` here; just use a  `Dictionary<string, string>` to create your dynamic property:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("dynamic_prop", "val");
var body = new
{
    prop1 = "val1",
    prop2 = "val2",
    prop3 = dict
};
```